# Material-UI Fill Icon

Tags: reactjs, svg, material-design, material-ui

I am adding the icon button in form of the start from and I want to fill it on click with solid color.

```
import StarIcon from '@material-ui/icons/StarBorder'
...
<IconButton><StarIcon className={classes.favoricon}/></IconButton>
```

I had a look at icon implementation, could not find a class that would control it (check code [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Icon/Icon.js)). I could create a separate svg, but maybe there is a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a better way.

Create a `state`on the component and modify the state whenever the Component is clicked.

Use `onClick` function to toggle the state which changes the Component from `StarIcon` to `Star` and vice-versa.

```js
handleChange = () => {
    const value = this.state.value;
    this.setState((prev) => ({value: !prev.value}));
  };
```